# Is any parametrization of a smooth curve smooth? Can we always find a smooth parametrization of a smooth curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

I assume that this must be true because the parametrization describes the same object, but I cannot recall a theorem that would state this explicitly.

Comment: What definition of smooth are we using this time?

Comment: @Arjang infinitely differentiable.

Comment: in that case if use a parametrisation from no where differentiable curve like Weistraus's example then I guess the answer is no.

Comment: @Arjang did you mean parametrization of e.g. Weierstrass function? I assume the curve being parametrized to be smooth.

Comment: Define a parametrisation from Weistaus function to your smooth curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take, for instance, the curve in $\mathbb R^2$ defined by $\gamma(t)=(t,t)$ ($t\in[-1,1]$). And now take the reparametrization $\eta(t)=\left(\sqrt[3]t,\sqrt[3]t\right)$ (again, with $t\in[-1,1]$).

Comment: Can we always find a smooth parametrization of a smooth curve?

Comment: Yes, by the definition of “smooth curve”.

Comment: Would a parametrisation from Weistaus function to the smooth curve also be used as counter example?

Comment: Yes. And  a more radical counterexample than mine, since it would be differentiable nowhere.